# how to get keys and values from a list to add to dictionary

Tags: python

so I'm trying to build a dictionary, where the key is the first element of a list and the rest of the elements are the values so it has the following format: 
{str: [str, str, str, int, str]} but right now I don't understand how to get the first element from the list as the key and the rest as the value. 
Here is an example:

this is the list

```
['asmith', 'Alice', 'Smith', '31', 'F', 'alice.smith@example.com']
```

first element[0] is the key and the rest are the value

Here is what I have so far:

```
def create_dict(my_file):
    information = my_file.read()
    information = information.split()
    res = []
    for element in information:
        res.append(element)
    print(res)
    print(res[0])
    d = dict((res[0], res[1:6]) for res[0] in res[1:6])
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comprehension is messed up here:

```
d = dict((res[0], res[1:6]) for res[0] in res[1:6])
```

You might do something like this in a loop, assuming that `res` is a list of lists:

```
d = {}
for r in res:
    d[r[0]] = r[1:6]
```

Or using comprehension:

```
d = {r[0]:r[1:6] for r in res}
```

Comment: using the comprehension this is the output im getting which is not correct:{'S': 'mith', 'F': '', 'A': 'lice', '3': '1', 'a': 'lice.'}

Comment: You need to provide MCVE of your input data. It looks like you are not paying attention to the caveat I mentioned in my answer ("assuming that `res` is a list of lists").  If `res` is a *single* list (not a nested list of lists) then yes the solution is not the same.

Comment: Otherwise, if your list only represents a *single* person, it seems pointless/redundant/unnecessary to cast this to a dict.  Please show in your question some example data for `information`.